# Vertical align middle for drop-down list

Tags: asp.net, css

I am styling a asp:DropDownList element with custom CSS.  I have set the height and am trying to get the text to appear in the middle of the element, rather than at the bottom. Vertical-align:middle does not seem to work, and if I add padding-bottom to push it up from the bottom, in IE there is an ugly gap between the arrow on the right of the drop-down and the border.  This is my CSS currently:

```
.dropdowndiv
{
    font-size:10pt;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    height:26px;
    width:220px;
    border:1px solid #d5d5d5;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.dropdowndiv
{
    font-size:10pt;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    height:26px;
    width:220px;
    border:1px solid #d5d5d5;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I changed the margin-bottom setting of 2px to a padding-bottom of 4px.

**UPDATE:**

Looked fine on mine, but you can add padding to any side to get it the way you wish.

Failing that you may want to look at Tag mapping - Lee Dumond suggested this on his blog in response to a similar problem I was experiencing at the time:

http://leedumond.com/blog/fixing-asp-net-server-control-rendering-issues-with-tag-mapping/

Comment: This puts the text in the right position, but as I mentioned in the initial question, it creates an unsightly gap between the border and the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a line height of 26px should align your text to the middle.

Comment: Thanks, but I've now got     height:26px;
    line-height:26px; but it still aligns on the bottom